# How to build Npgsql?

Tags: c#, build, npgsql, dnx

I'm trying to contribute to the Npgsql project with a feature that I need, which is support for the **GREATEST** postgre function. (Convert a > b ? a : b to greatest instead of CASE statements)

But I can't make it compile because there are many *MethodName* **Async** that doesn't exist.

I guess that the **AsyncRewriter** package takes care of method generation but I don't know how.

Does anyone have experience contributing to the project?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Npgsql uses code generation to create async methods based on sync user-written methods. This is a step in the build that happens before compilation, and creates the GeneratedAsync.cs file.

If you're trying to build with DNX (project.json), this step has very recently been integrated into the build via a DNX project command, and added as a prebuild script - so async rewriting should happen transparently when you run `dnu build`.

Can you make sure you're on the absolute latest dev commit?

Comment: Yes, I have forked the develop branch and it says that is even with the original branch.How do I run the dnu build? The project.json have a   "commands": {
    "rewrite-async": "AsyncRewriter"
  }, so I believe it's correct.

Comment: Ok I figured out I just have to run the dnu restore before running the dnu build. Thanks!